# Ruby: adding initialize to parent class leads to "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: ruby

Why do I get "wrong number of arguments" if I remove the comments for the second initializer? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3. Thanks for any help!

```
class Parent
  def initialize
    puts "Parent initialize"
  end

#  def initialize(str)
#    puts "Parent initialize: #{str}"
#  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def initialize
    puts "Child initialize"
    super()
  end
end

Child.new
```

Comment: Why would you think you would NOT get that error? `initialize` takes 1 argument in the commented example, you are calling `super()` with no arguments. That's the "wrong number of arguments". (edit: nvm, OP means having BOTH initialize methods at once)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot perform method overloading in Ruby. If you uncomment the second `initialize` method in `Parent`, that will overwrite the first one and become the one and only `initialize` method.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby does not have method overloading. Instead you can use default arguments:

```
class Parent
  def initialize(str = nil)
    if str.nil?
      puts "Parent initialize"
    else
      puts "Parent initialize: #{str}"
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def initialize
    puts "Child initialize"
    super()
  end
end

Child.new
```